# Error deserializing DateTime JSON fields in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: json, deserialization, .net-core-3.0

I've got a WPF / .Net Core 3.0 app which is consuming a Web API.
It executes a GET on an API endpoint and then tries to deserialize the JSON.
However, it's giving an error when trying to deserialize the DateTime fields.
Here's the code:

```
private HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

private async Task GetClients()
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ClientGetDto>));
    var streamTask = httpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://mywebapp.com/api/Clients");
    List<ClientGetDto> clientDtos = serializer.ReadObject(await streamTask) as List<ClientGetDto>;
}
```

The ClientGetDto model looks like this:

```
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string FranchiseName { get; set; }
    public int? ProLicenses { get; set; }
    public int? LiteLicenses { get; set; }
    public int? ProSalesLicenses { get; set; }
    public int? LiteSalesLicenses { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartOfAgreementDate { get; set; }
    public int? DebitOrderDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DebitOrderStartDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? ContractAmount { get; set; }
    public bool? DebitOrderFormReceived { get; set; }
    public bool? CancellationReceived { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CancellationDate { get; set; }
    public string CompanyRegNo { get; set; }
    public string DbUrl { get; set; }
    public string DbName { get; set; }
    public double? CloudStorageQuota { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int? FranchiseId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsTestDb { get; set; }
    public bool? IsGumtreeRegistered { get; set; }
    public int? FusionClientId { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

and the JSON that is returned by the API is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "clientCode": "cx0007",
    "apiUrl": "https://mywebapp/api",
    "companyName": "ACME Company",
    "franchiseName": "ACME Franchise",
    "proLicenses": 1,
    "liteLicenses": 0,
    "proSalesLicenses": 0,
    "liteSalesLicenses": 0,
    "isActive": true,
    "startOfAgreementDate": "2007-08-01T00:00:00",
    "debitOrderDay": 1,
    "debitOrderStartDate": "2012-03-01T00:00:00",
    "contractAmount": 695.00,
    "debitOrderFormReceived": true,
    "cancellationReceived": false,
    "cancellationDate": "2012-10-18T00:00:00",
    "companyRegNo": "",
    "dbUrl": "mydb.co.za",
    "dbName": "db1",
    "cloudStorageQuota": 5.0,
    "comments": null,
    "franchiseId": null,
    "isTestDb": false,
    "isGumtreeRegistered": false,
    "fusionClientId": null,
    "countryCode": "US"
  },
  ...
]
```

The error I'm getting is:

> "There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PropWorxManager.DTOs.ClientGetDto,
>   PropWorxManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]. 
>   DateTime content '2007-08-01T00:00:00' does not
>   start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for
>   JSON."}   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

After some research I tried this:

```
var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeFormat = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DateTimeFormat("o")
};
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ClientGetDto>), settings);
```

But that then gives this error:

> "There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PropWorxManager.DTOs.ClientGetDto,
>   PropWorxManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]. 
>   String '2007-08-01T00:00:00' was not recognized
>   as a valid
>   DateTime."}   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thank you.

P.S. The API is also written in .Net Core 3.0 if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeFormat = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DateTimeFormat("o")
};
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ClientGetDto>), settings);
```